# How to increase the length of url in ASP.Net 4.0?

Tags: c#, iis-6, asp.net-4.0

What are the best practices that I can follow to increase the max length of the URL in ASP.NET 4.0 with IIS 6.0?

**I am getting this error - The remote server returned an error: (414) Request-URI Too Large.**

I want to send the sms to 1200 phone number's, Its approx. 13500 characters.

I am using this code.

```
string strUrl = "http://mobicomm.dove-sms.com/mobicomm//submitsms.jsp?user=****&key=****&mobile=" + mob + "&message=" + txtMessage.Text.Trim() + "&senderid=****&accusage=1";

        // Create a request object  
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(strUrl);
        // Get the response back  
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream s = (Stream)response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(s);
        string dataString = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
        s.Close();
        readStream.Close();
```

Comment: It seems that the phone numbers is posted in the URL (Like a `GET`-request, instead of `POST`), see if you can send it as `POST` instead. What does your code look like when you send the sms?

Comment: Yes, the best practices are to *not* send a huge amount of data in the URL

Comment: It's a web API of sms gate way so I had to send it through url only.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a POST and include your params in the body of the request.

Comment: Yes, that is very reasonable

Comment: Yes, I am posting the parameters in the request url.

Comment: @abhishek you might want to look up the difference between a POST and a GET. The SMS Gateway webapi will definitely support POST-like methods. If you are unsure about this, share a link to the gateway provider so we can help you figure it out.